# How to create two different LinearLayout in a same ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

i want to combine two LinearLayout, both have different TextView arrangement in them, in a single ListView. so the final look should be like below:

[image]

and i run it with my code, but the app wouldn't start. below are my code.

**Activity class**:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    // Create list of items
    String[] publicModeItems = {
            "AAAAA", 
            "BBBBB"
    };

    String[] publicModeParameters = {
            "YES", 
            "NO"
    };

    String[] publicModeResetExe = {
            "CCCCC",
            "DDDDD"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {

        CustomList adapter1 = new CustomList(this, publicModeItems, publicModeParameters);

        // Build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,                       // context for the activity
                R.layout.text_view_test,    // layout to use (create)
                publicModeResetExe);        // items to display

        // Configure the list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PublicModeListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    private class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] publicModeItems;
        private final String[] publicModeParameters;

        public CustomList(Activity context, 
                String[] publicModeItems, 
                String[] publicModeParameters) {
            super(context, R.layout.text_views_1, publicModeItems);
            this.context = context;
            this.publicModeItems = publicModeItems;
            this.publicModeParameters = publicModeParameters;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutinflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.text_views_1, null, true);
            TextView txtPublicModeItems = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PublicModeItems);
            TextView txtPublicModeParameters = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PublicModeParameters);
            txtPublicModeItems.setText(publicModeItems[position]);
            txtPublicModeParameters.setText(publicModeParameters[position]);

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

**text_views_1 xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/PublicModeLayoutForTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PublicModeItems"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_change" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PublicModeOpenBracket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="["
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_change" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PublicModeParameters"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_change" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PublicModeCloseBracket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="]"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_change" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**text_view_test xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_change" >

</TextView>
```

**activity_main xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/PublicModeListViewLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.mycalendar.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/PublicModeListViewLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/PublicModeListView"
            android:layout_width="308dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="@color/yellow"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Problem** : I just run my code just now, and only 'CCCCC' and 'DDDDD' is showing. so do you have any idea on this?

Comment: oh sorry! i just run my code just now, and only 'CCCCC' and 'DDDDD' is showing. so do you have any idea on this?

Comment: There is no need of 2 adapters, you can bind all data in `ArrayList` and pass it to adapter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should inherit your list adapter from **BaseAdapter** rather than **ArrayAdapter**.
2. Rewrite adapter's *getView()* method to inflate layout according position, like below.

> ```
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     ...
>     View rootView = null;
>     if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
>         rootView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.text_views_1, null, true);
>     } else {
>         rootView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.text_views, null, true);
>     }
>     ...
>     return rootView;
> }
> ```

Comment: hey, i try your suggestion but BaseAdapter force me to unimplemented methods which are `public int getCount()`, `public Object getItem()` and `public long getItemId()`. for the getCount, what value should I return?

and one more thing is, why your condition of `position` is `0 || 1`?

Comment: getCount() is your total rows of list view. position condition of 0,1 is based on your question screenshot. You need decide which row return which view.

Comment: so means that, for above picture, i need to `return 4` for the `getCount()` right?

Answer (score 0):

You set the list adapter twice

```
list.setAdapter(adapter1);
list.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

in this case the current adapter is the second, not them both.
Use `ListView` with `SimpleAdapter` or a custom adapter and that will solve all your problems, check out this for `SimpleAdapter` [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html) to learn a the basics and this [tutorial](http://www.geeks.gallery/listview-using-simpleadapter-in-android/) to learn how you can make multiple views instead of just 1. This  [tutorial](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) is about creating custom adapter
BTW, I have few comments on your code and xml layout
**First**, there is no need for 2 `TextView`s for your bracket, you can easily add them programmatically to the `String[]` or even to YES/NO `TextView`.
**Second**, You're not using a `ViewHolder` in your `CustomList` adapter and this is not a good practice as every time you scroll your list, it creates new view although it can use already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this problem. but it seems not so convenient to use this method.

```
public class PublicModeActivity extends Activity {

    // Create list of items
    String[] publicModeItems = {
            "AAAAA", 
            "BBBBB"
    };

    String[] publicModeParameters = {
            "YES", 
            "NO"

    String[] publicModeResEx = {
            "",
            "",
            "CCCCC",
            "DDDDD"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, publicModeItems, publicModeParameters, publicModeResEx);

        // Configure the list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PublicModeListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] publicModeItems;
        private final String[] publicModeParameters;
        private final String[] publicModeResEx;

        public CustomList(Activity context, 
                String[] publicModeItems, 
                String[] publicModeParameters,
                String[] publicModeResEx) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.publicModeItems = publicModeItems;
            this.publicModeParameters = publicModeParameters;
            this.publicModeResEx = publicModeResEx;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutinflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = null;
            Log.i("PublicModeActivity", "" + position);
            if (position < 2) {
                rowView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.text_views_1, null, true);
                TextView txtPublicModeItems = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PublicModeItems);
                TextView txtPublicModeParameters = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PublicModeParameters);
                txtPublicModeItems.setText(publicModeItems[position]);
                txtPublicModeParameters.setText(publicModeParameters[position]);
            } else {
                rowView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view_test, null, true);
                TextView txtPublicModeResEx = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.PublicModeResEx);
                txtPublicModeResEx.setText(publicModeResEx[position]);
            }
            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to put that blank string `"",` to match the number of row with the upper layout (`text_views_1`) even-though those blank string are use in different layout. so it is not so convenient especially when you want to display so many data. If someone here have much simpler method than this. feel free to share with me/us. i'm eager to learn. thank you!